# is it possible to get files from a root directory and sub directories with glob?

Tags: php

I'm working on a script that when ran uses glob() to get all the files from a directory that is passed through an arg, and then check their modification time. Is it possible to have glob() go through the files in the dir, and the files in the sub dirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `glob()` a requirement? For a recursive implementation I prefer using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator()`. This does the same job in a much more readable way.

```
$realpath = realpath('/path/to/file');


$fileObjects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($realpath));

foreach($fileObjects as $key => $object){
    echo $object->getFilename();
}
```

Comment: It's possible, I'll have to look at that more. I assume this comes bundled with PHP?

Comment: Yes, it uses the StandardPHPLibrary (SPL) iterators.